# Append video (once) data type to image gallery overlay with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a jQuery lightbox for an image gallery that includes support for a video. I have created next and previous functions so that when a user clicks on the next or previous arrows in the overlay the click function iterates through the gallery. I have also created keyboard navigation via the keydown() event handler.

I have encountered a couple of bugs with the video. It appears in the overlay (as it should) when I click on the image thumbnail from the DOM, but when I get to the video via the arrows &/or keyboard navigation the alignment of the video gets thrown off and there are double posts of the video when clicking forward and back.

Has anyone ever encountered these bugs when trying to add video functionality to am image gallery lightbox, and if so, how should I approach getting the video to appear only once in the overlay (as well as being centered). I am quite new at jQuery and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Here is my project website:

[Lightgallery](http://firebuggirl.github.io/lightgallery/)

..and here is my repo on Github:

[Lightgallery repo](https://github.com/firebuggirl/lightgallery)

Answer (score 0):

You will laugh at this:

On line 186 in you app.js you forgot to add `class="video"` to your video `<iframe>`.

You should now have this instead:

```
var $video = ('<iframe class="video" src="'+videoURL+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't see this sooner. I know, it feels silly to have missed something so obvious, but it happens...lol...Especially when you're in the process of learning. Anyhoo...Thanks for responding!